# Makefile pattern rule either ignores phony rule or spontaneously deletes output file

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I'm trying to write a makefile to produce several output files for each of several sources, using pattern rules.

I have the following `Makefile` (GNU Make 3.8.1):

```
all : foo.all bar.all

%.all : %.pdf %.svg
    @echo Made $*

%.pdf :
    touch $@

%.svg :
    touch $@

.PHONY: foo.all bar.all
```

Since `*.all` do not represent real output files, I tried marking them as [`.PHONY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile). However, running `make` then doesn't work:

```
$ ls
Makefile
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

According to `make -d`:

```
 No implicit rule found for `all'.
  Considering target file `foo.all'.
   File `foo.all' does not exist.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `foo.all'.
  Must remake target `foo.all'.
  Successfully remade target file `foo.all'.
  Considering target file `bar.all'.
   File `bar.all' does not exist.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `bar.all'.
  Must remake target `bar.all'.
  Successfully remade target file `bar.all'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
Must remake target `all'.
Successfully remade target file `all'.
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

which seems to be pretending to run the `%.all` rules, but skipping the bodies.

But with the `.PHONY` line commented out, Make runs the targets, but then spontaneously decides to delete the output files:

```
$ make
touch foo.pdf
touch foo.svg
Made foo
touch bar.pdf
touch bar.svg
Made bar
rm foo.pdf foo.svg bar.pdf bar.svg
```

According to `make -d`, it says:

```
Removing intermediate files...
```

## Minimal example

A minimal example giving anomalous behavior:

```
%.all: %.out
    @echo Made $*

%.out:
    touch $@
```

I expect running `make somefile.all` to cause it to create the file `somefile.out`, but it gets deleted:

```
$ make somefile.all
touch somefile.out
Made somefile
rm somefile.out
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [another previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095569/when-declaring-the-pattern-rule-as-phony-it-is-not-triggered?rq=1) though it's not obvious.  Read the responses about using `.PHONY` to match pattern rules.

Answer (score 3):

#### Keeping make from deleting intermediary files

I recommend against using `.PRECIOUS` (see below as to why). Using `.SECONDARY` would preserve the `.out` files:

```
TARGETS=foo bar
all: $(TARGETS:=.all)

%.all: %.out
    @echo Made $*

%.out:
    touch $@

.SECONDARY: $(TARGETS:=.out)
```

`$(TARGETS:=.all)` just appends `.all` to all names in `TARGETS`. `$(TARGETS:=.out)` appends `.out`. We apparently cannot use `%.out` as a target of `.SECONDARY`. These just save having to relist all targets individually.

I prefer to not use `.PRECIOUS` for this because [the documentation says](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets)

> if make is killed or interrupted during the execution of their recipes, the target is not deleted.

This can leave corrupted files in the file system. Here's an example.

```
all: foo.all bar.all

%.all: %.out
    @echo Made $*

%.out:
    sh -e -c 'echo "{1, 2, 3" > $@; FAIL!; echo "}" >> $@'

.PRECIOUS: %.out
```

The FAIL! command simulates a tool that crashes in the middle of its work. Here's a shell session working with the Makefile above:

```
$ ls
Makefile
$ make
sh -e -c 'echo "{1, 2, 3" > foo.out; FAIL!; echo "}" >> foo.out'
sh: 1: FAIL!: not found
make: *** [foo.out] Error 127
$ cat foo.out
{1, 2, 3
```

Yikes... my `foo.out` file is incomplete. Let's try making again:

```
$ make
Made foo
sh -e -c 'echo "{1, 2, 3" > bar.out; FAIL!; echo "}" >> bar.out'
sh: 1: FAIL!: not found
make: *** [bar.out] Error 127
$ cat *.out
{1, 2, 3
{1, 2, 3
```

Make is none the wiser about files left around by earlier runs so when you run make again, it will take the corrupted files at face value. `foo.out` was not remade (despite the "Made foo" message) because it already exists and the Makefile went straight to trying to make bar.

`.SECONDARY` makes it so that:

> The targets which .SECONDARY depends on are treated as intermediate files, except that they are never automatically deleted.

This means they are never automatically deleted just *because they are intermediate files*. The default make behavior of deleting targets that were being rebuilt if the tool rebuilding them crashed is not affected.

#### Using `.PHONY` with pattern rules

It seems though that `.PHONY` works only for targets that are explicit, not inferred. I've not found documentation confirming this. However, this works:

```
TARGETS:=foo bar
TARGETS_all:=$(TARGETS:=.all)

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS_all)

.PHONY: $(TARGETS_all)
$(TARGETS_all): %.all: %.out
    @echo Made $*

%.out:
    touch $@

.SECONDARY: $(TARGETS:=.out)
```

In this rule `$(TARGETS_all): %.all: %.out` `$(TARGETS_all):` gives the list of targets to which the pattern can be applied. It makes `foo.all` and `bar.all` explicit targets. Without this, they would be inferred targets.

You can test that it works by creating file called `foo.all` in your directory and run make over and over. The `foo.all` file has no effect on make.

Comment: I can only guess that ``.PHONY`` needs explicit targets. I've updated my answer with what I found.

Comment: @Louis **We apparently cannot use %.out as a target of .SECONDARY.** Seems another confirmation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625394/secondary-for-a-pattern-rule-with-gnu-make what would answer my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090032/why-make-remove-intermediate-file-even-with-secondary-and-require-to-use-preci

Comment: Here's the doc to that double colon target/dep line: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage

Answer (score 2):

Your `somefile.out` files are considered [intermediate](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules) by GNU make, which is why they are automatically deleted in your example.  You can instruct GNU make to preserve these files by use the of `.PRECIOUS` special target, like this:

```
%.all: %.out
    @echo Made $*

%.out:
    touch $@

.PRECIOUS: %.out
```