# Makefile rule to keep intermediate files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

To debug a complex XSLT transformation I broke it into several parts: first I build `%.1.xml`, then I use it to build `%.2.xml`, and finally I build `%.3.xml`. It all works fine, but if I ask Make to build the last one, then Make invariably deletes the intermediate `%.1.xml` and `%.2.xml`, and I'd rather keep them. I've tried to mark all `.xml` files as `.PRECIOUS` so:

```
.PRECIOUS: %.xml
```

but this didn't seem to work. (I also tried to use `%.1.xml` and `%.2.xml`, but this didn't work either. I then tried to mark them as `.SECONDARY` in the same manner and with the same negative result. The only way it doesn't delete the intermediate files is when the files already exist; in this case it only rebuilds them. But if the files do not exist, it always deletes them.

What am I missing?

GNU Make 4.1.

**Update:** the Makefile, `>>` stands for `TAB`:

```
sample-%.1.xml: sample-%.0.xml job.1.xslt job.xslt
   >>   xsltproc $(filter %.1.xslt,$^) $(filter %.xml,$^) > $@
sample-%.2.xml: sample-%.1.xml job.2.xslt job.xslt
   >>   xsltproc $(filter %.2.xslt,$^) $(filter %.xml,$^) > $@
sample-%.3.xml: sample-%.2.xml job.3.xslt job.xslt
   >>   xsltproc $(filter %.3.xslt,$^) $(filter %.xml,$^) > $@
.SECONDARY: %.xml   # or .PRECIOUS: %.xml
```

It works fine, rebuilds everything or builds intermediate files as required, but when asked to build `.3.xml` and `.1.xml` and `.2.xml` do not exist, it builds them and then deletes at the end. If `.1.xml` exists, but `.2.xml` doesn't, it will rebuild all and delete `.2.xml`. It's not a show-stopper, of course, but I want to understand :)

Comment: Show you Makefile! :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in a simple makefile.  Please create a small self-contained example and post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to reproduce this issue, but only when using target names based on patterns! Sadly, neither `.SECONDARY`, nor `.PRECIOUS` worked when trying to aggregate more targets in a pattern (they work as expected if the target names are just plain strings!).

I found a workaround though ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625394/secondary-for-a-pattern-rule-with-gnu-make)). When `.SECONDARY:` is used with no associated targets, this actually converts *ALL* the intermediate targets to `.SECONDARY` and that solved the problem.

Comment: There is some logic to it: the left side has no pattern to match the right side, hence it ignores it. I guess a wildcard would also work.